# In LINQ, what is the main difference/usefulness between .Any<> and .Where<> to test for records existance

Tags: .net, linq

For example, if I had a Linq to SQL data context, or if I had ADO.NET Entity Framework entities that mapped to a database table, and I want to test for a single Customer...

Is there much difference between:

```
MyDatabaseContext.Customers.Any(c => c.CustomerId == 3)
```

and

```
MyDatabaseContext.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerId == 3)
```

.Any<> - return type bool

.Where<> - return type IQueryable

EDIT: Corrected question wording after accepting answer from Fredrik Mörk - thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check the documentation again:

- [`Any<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) returns a `bool` indicating whether at least one item meets the criteria
- [`Where<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable` containing the items that meet the criteria

There may be a performance difference in that `Any` stops as soon as it can determine the result (when it finds a matching item), while `Where` will need to always loop over all items before returning the result. So if you only need to check whether there are any matching items, `Any` will be the method for the job.

Comment: nitpick: Where will return an IEnumerable when used in a Linq to objects context. The OP gave the example as a Linq to SQL context so it would return an IQueryable. Not that it matters much. The best would be to write `IEnumerable/IQueryable`, or sequence.

Comment: @Martinho: good points. However, I would still argue that `Where<>` returns an `IEnumerable` for a couple of reasons: one is that `IQueryable` inherits `IEnumerable`. Another reason is that when dealing with interfaces I usually prefer to stick to the interface defined by the contract, rather than what is *actually* returned by the underlying provider. That way the code is less dependent on the internals of the called methods, making it more portable.

Comment: "while Where will need to always loop over all items before returning the result" Not always true. For instance, in LINQ to objects, since the returned `IEnumerable<T>` is evaluated lazily, if you add a `.Any()` to `.Where(something)`, it **won't** loop over all items.

Answer (score 3):

`Any` returns a `bool` while `Where` returns an `IQueryable`. Being lazy, one would expect `Any` to terminate as soon as one satisfying element is found (returning true) while `Where` will search them all.

If you want to select a single customer, [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534800.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`Any()` returns a bool. I.e. are there any elements matching the condition. Use `Any()` if you just want to know if you have elements to work with. E.g. prefer `Any()` over `Count() == 0` for instance as the latter will possible enumerate the entire sequence to find out if it is empty or not.

`Where()` returns a sequence of the elements matching the condition.

Answer (score 2):

`Any<>` checks whether any items satisfy the criterion, i.e. returns `bool`, meaning that it only has to find the first item, which can be very fast. Whereas `Where<>` enumerates all the items that satisfy the condition, meaning that it has to iterate the whole collection.

Answer (score 1):

Any tests the lambda/predicate and returns true/false

Where returns the set of objects for which lambda/predicate holds true as IQueryable